# python 3x - aggregate pandas df rows and columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, aggregate, row

I am reading a csv file into a pandas dataframe which has duplicate values for the rows and columns that I need to agregate (both rows and cols).

The csv file looks like this:

| p/q/[val] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 85.09227753 | 79.70470428 | 14.60372257 | 35.94606018 | 38.66883087 | 43.14413452 | 62.1992569 | 61.9662056 | 47.01652908 | 55.35105515 |
| 1 | 77.67690277 | 72.28933716 | 35.8657341 | 10.12055206 | 22.38080597 | 35.09898376 | 39.91122818 | 48.39712524 | 37.95729065 | 42.97728348 |
| 1 | 71.51867676 | 66.13111115 | 38.59518433 | 22.38080406 | 11.31649399 | 29.02029228 | 43.14096069 | 44.00777054 | 41.19556427 | 36.96442413 |
| 2 | 78.38805389 | 73.00048828 | 34.14358902 | 35.09897995 | 29.02029228 | 13.26141262 | 36.20913696 | 52.90936279 | 36.04150391 | 41.10220718 |
| 2 | 87.69218445 | 82.30461884 | 62.14162445 | 39.91123581 | 43.14096451 | 36.20913696 | 15.41283798 | 52.42485428 | 53.06882477 | 55.80033112 |
| 2 | 68.89026642 | 63.50270844 | 52.83700562 | 45.54430771 | 41.67800522 | 48.60984421 | 50.78954315 | 13.5169096 | 37.65000153 | 36.0362854 |
| 3 | 71.05574036 | 65.66817474 | 37.6963768 | 34.8531723 | 41.11572266 | 36.43598175 | 55.10356522 | 39.11390305 | 11.24700832 | 23.63844109 |
| 3 | 68.75523376 | 63.36768723 | 46.03090668 | 43.18769836 | 49.4425621 | 45.19208527 | 53.05971527 | 39.51002502 | 23.63843918 | 11.75947094 |
| 4 | 71.51867676 | 66.13111115 | 38.59518433 | 22.38080406 | 11.31649399 | 29.02029228 | 43.14096069 | 44.00777054 | 41.19556427 | 36.96442413 |
| 4 | 68.89026642 | 63.50270844 | 52.83700562 | 45.54430771 | 41.67800522 | 48.60984421 | 50.78954315 | 13.5169096 | 37.65000153 | 36.0362854 |

When I read the csv file into a pandas df, it converts the duplicated column names to decimal numbers and looks like this:

| p/q/[val] | 1 | 1.1 | 1.2 | 2 | 2.1 | 2.2 | 3 | 3.1 | 4 | 4.1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 85.09227753 | 79.70470428 | 14.60372257 | 35.94606018 | 38.66883087 | 43.14413452 | 62.1992569 | 61.9662056 | 47.01652908 | 55.35105515 |
| 1 | 77.67690277 | 72.28933716 | 35.8657341 | 10.12055206 | 22.38080597 | 35.09898376 | 39.91122818 | 48.39712524 | 37.95729065 | 42.97728348 |
| 1 | 71.51867676 | 66.13111115 | 38.59518433 | 22.38080406 | 11.31649399 | 29.02029228 | 43.14096069 | 44.00777054 | 41.19556427 | 36.96442413 |
| 2 | 78.38805389 | 73.00048828 | 34.14358902 | 35.09897995 | 29.02029228 | 13.26141262 | 36.20913696 | 52.90936279 | 36.04150391 | 41.10220718 |
| 2 | 87.69218445 | 82.30461884 | 62.14162445 | 39.91123581 | 43.14096451 | 36.20913696 | 15.41283798 | 52.42485428 | 53.06882477 | 55.80033112 |
| 2 | 68.89026642 | 63.50270844 | 52.83700562 | 45.54430771 | 41.67800522 | 48.60984421 | 50.78954315 | 13.5169096 | 37.65000153 | 36.0362854 |
| 3 | 71.05574036 | 65.66817474 | 37.6963768 | 34.8531723 | 41.11572266 | 36.43598175 | 55.10356522 | 39.11390305 | 11.24700832 | 23.63844109 |
| 3 | 68.75523376 | 63.36768723 | 46.03090668 | 43.18769836 | 49.4425621 | 45.19208527 | 53.05971527 | 39.51002502 | 23.63843918 | 11.75947094 |
| 4 | 71.51867676 | 66.13111115 | 38.59518433 | 22.38080406 | 11.31649399 | 29.02029228 | 43.14096069 | 44.00777054 | 41.19556427 | 36.96442413 |
| 4 | 68.89026642 | 63.50270844 | 52.83700562 | 45.54430771 | 41.67800522 | 48.60984421 | 50.78954315 | 13.5169096 | 37.65000153 | 36.0362854 |

I need to aggregate the rows and the columns so my final dataframe looks like this:

| p/q/[val] | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 60.1641834 | 27.56410641 | 49.93709119 | 43.57702446 |
| 2 | 66.98894882 | 36.94157547 | 36.87710746 | 43.28319232 |
| 3 | 58.76235326 | 41.70453707 | 46.69680214 | 17.57083988 |
| 4 | 60.24582545 | 33.09162458 | 37.863796 | 37.96156883 |

In Excel I can do this in two steps using the following formulae:

**Step1 - aggregate the rows**:

[image]

**Step2 - aggregate the columns**:

[image]

I am just not sure how I can do this in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really have the same indices per column/row:

```py
(df
 .set_index('p/q/[val]')
 .groupby(level=0).mean()
 .groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean()
 )
```

Alternative:

```py
(df
 .melt(id_vars='p/q/[val]')
 .groupby(['p/q/[val]', 'variable'])['value'].mean()
 .unstack()
 )
```

Output:

```
                  1          2          3          4
p/q/[val]                                            
1          60.164183  27.564106  49.937091  43.577024
2          66.988949  36.941575  36.877107  43.283192
3          58.762353  41.704537  46.696802  17.570840
4          60.245825  33.091625  37.863796  37.961569
```

If the columns are on the form 1, 1.1, etc, add a `rename` step:

```py
(df
 .set_index('p/q/[val]')
 .rename(columns=lambda x: x.rpartition('.')[0])  # or x[0] if single digits
 .groupby(level=0).mean()
 .groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean()
 )
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response. This aggregates the rows correctly but not the columns. The columns still give decimals for each duplicated number (1        1.1        1.2  ...        3.1          4        4.1).

Comment: @Genspec mozway's answer is based on the premise that you do indeed have identically named columns... do you in fact have have 1 and 1.1 and 1.2 etc?

Comment: Yes, I just saw the output of the df from importing a csv. The csv has the duplicated header numbers but when I read it into a df it creates the decimal numbers.

Comment: @Genspec might want to update your question then as it's a bit misleading...

Comment: @Genspec see the update, add a `rename` step to homogenize the names

Comment: Which now seems to produce completely different results than the OP expects?

Comment: @Jon I used the wrong aggregation... was mean, not sum...

Comment: Thanks not @mozway and jon. I saw the sum vs mean and this is working perfectly. Thanks so much for you quick assistance with this.

Comment: @mozway I might be tempted to go for a `.rename(columns=lambda c: c.partition('.')[0])` for a bit of robustness but... (should there ever be 10 or more columns etc...)

Comment: @Jon I hesitated to go for a `x.rsplit('.')[0]` but it's not fully fail proof of there are dots on the names, maybe a regex? In the end I opted for the simple example leaving this to handle to OP ;)

Comment: `.partition` is better - it only splits once and is about 30% faster than `.split` even if you provide `split(maxsplit=1)`... (and from what I remember - even faster when no split is necessary and you're always guaranteed a 3-tuple return from it)

Comment: Good to know, you convinced me ;)

Comment: Thanks for keeping this going. I just accessed a table with loads more columns and I was wondering why I was only getting the first 9 columns. The .rpartition seems to be working for larger csv files. Thanks once again.

Comment: @JonClements I just did a check on the results and it does not take the column with an integer as the header. If I have a header 2 & 2.1 with vals 5 and 10 respectfully, with the code supplied I gave a mean value of 10 and I should be getting 7.5. I am not sure how to fix the code to include the integer column names.

Comment: A simple way might be to convert the names to string

Comment: @mozway, they are already strings: Index([<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, ... --->p/q/[val]    1  1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4 ...

Comment: @mozway, I used a bit of a workaround. I first reset the columns with a find/replace by splitting the column names (in_df.columns = [col.split(".")[0] for col in in_df.columns]), then I use your code without the .rename (out_df = in_df.set_index('p/q/[val]').groupby(level=0).mean().groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean()). This seems to work and includes all the columns now

Comment: @Genspec great customization, glad you found a way by yourself ;)